# Enable Keyword speech recognition manually for mrtk2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

There is an option to set a manual start behavior in the "Mixed Reality Speech Commands Profile"s. How do I access it and toggle the speech input?
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/speech?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) gives no information about this.

I can disable and enable the eyetracker like this:

```
CoreServices.InputSystem.EyeGazeProvider.IsEyeTrackingEnabled
```

Though I cannot find an option to do so for the SpeechHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to manually get this DataProvider and then enable it. You can refer to the code below and this document - [WindowsSpeechInputProvider Class (Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Windows.Input) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.windows.input.windowsspeechinputprovider?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.8.0).

```
CoreServices.GetInputSystemDataProvider<WindowsSpeechInputProvider>().StartRecognition();
```